# git is out of date after a Time Machine restore

Tags: git, timemachine

I just reverted my Mac back to its state 10 days ago using Time Machine. I then updated my website's repository folder back to 1 day ago to keep coding.

When I run `git status` or `gitk`, it shows the 10-day old view, not the current view, so it's missing some recent commits. Where is the folder/file I have to update to get the current data?

In case this clarification is needed, my `origin` on Github has commits from 6/10, 6/7, 6/1, and 5/30. My faulty `git status` only shows commits 6/1 and 5/30, and the other files are just floating around in the staging area as if never committed.

Comment: You probably need to pull the changes from github; you've lost those changes when you recovered your 10-day-old repository.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I fixed the problem by manually restoring the hidden .git folder - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem's cause

My local folder contains a hidden .git folder, which is the local repository (thanks @JonathanLeffer).
Time Machine did not restore the .git folder when I selected all files in my repository for a manual restore.

#### Solution

I manually restored .git to its state as of 1 day ago, making sure to choose 'replace' for all files to make sure the old files are overwritten with the newer ones.
After running `gitk`, all commits are visible for 6/10, 6/7, 6/1, and 5/30.

Comment: The `.git` folder _is_ the Git repository (or the local version of it).  So, if Time Machine didn't restore it, that's a pain (thanks for the warning).  Of course, restoring a more recent version of the repository than the 10-day old one simplifies your life.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems that Time Machine doesn't automatically restore hidden items - I wish Apple at least gives its users a warning to avoid the problems that inevitably result!

Comment: Sounds like you made it more difficult than it should be. If your repo is uploaded to GitHub or any other server and contains more recent commits than the version you have restored on your computer, all you should need to do is to make a PULL and all the commits made after the point to which your computer was restored will be downloaded to your local git repo... It is not more complicated then getting the latest code on a completely new machine...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with time machine, but this sounds a bit like what can happen when you share a repo across multiple computers with dropbox or spideroak or the like. The system basically tries to keep up with your work in the repo, but it's optimised for background work and for not disturbing your active use of the computer, so if it's not 100% tracked all file changes in your .git folder from one computer to the other, you can get a repo that is broken. I'm wondering if this kind of action in your backup system has caused the same issue?

Anyway - try making a new empty repo folder and pulling a whole fresh new copy of the project from github.